# How to Auto Login to a web-site?

Tags: url, authentication, vbscript, web, applescript

**Hello,**

I need to login to a web-site automatically. It is a dashboard. Is there a URL link code which I can create as shortcut link or ***VBScript*** code to achieve this? Also is there a ***AppleScript*** for MAC?

Comment: For applescript you could test with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437405/javascript-to-populate-form-and-submit-form

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a javascript bookmarklet that creates a form hidden in a div at the bottom of the current page and then submits it. (I included a time stamp cause many dashboard logins include a hidden timestamp field in the form.)

```
javascript:self.moveTo(0,0);self.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).innerHTML='<form%20name="BletForm"%20method="POST"%20action="https://secure.mysite.com/index.asp?action=login"><input%20type="hidden"%20name=“domain”%20value=“mydomain”%20/><input%20type="hidden"%20name="username"%20value=“myname”%20/><input%20type="hidden"%20name="password"%20value=“mypassword"%20/><input%20type="hidden"%20name="hidDateTime"%20id="idhidDateTime"%20value=""%20/></form>';document.getElementById('idhidDateTime').value=+new%20Date()%20/1000%20|0;document.forms%5B'BletForm'%5D.submit();
```

You can use that code along with do javascript in safari for an Applescript solution. Something like:

```
set jsCode to "document.body.app..."
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript jsCode in current tab of window 1
end tell
```