# Making AppleScript fill form

Tags: applescript

the problem I'm having is making me sick. I'm working over an applescript that throws action to fill form. I think I'm having an issue while getting it to wait until the site is loaded in 100%. The script activates the site but doesn't fill the forms. Please navigate me and help to work out this lazy script:

```
tell application "Safari"
set loginurl to "http://www.dogomania.pl/forum/register.php"
set mylogin to "worker100"
set mypassword to "blackie698"
tell application "Safari"
    make new document at end of documents
    set URL of document 1 to loginurl
    delay 4
    do JavaScript "document.forms['regusername']['username'].value = '" & mylogin & "'" in document 1
    do JavaScript "document.forms['password']['password'].value = '" & mypassword & "'" in document 1
end tell
```

end tell

Comment: The problem is not just with the timing, because if I load that url, and then run just your do javascript lines, it still doesn't work. You sure that's the correct url, btw? You could try a different method, which is to create the form yourself and submit it.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414846/how-to-auto-login-to-a-web-site/21443387#21443387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you simply have the form id/hierarchy wrong. This worked for me:

```
tell application "Safari"
  do JavaScript "document.forms['registerform']['regusername'].value = '" & mylogin & "'" in document 1
end tell
```

... and use the same form id for the 'password' field and other fields.

or you can do this, too, and only worry about the specific element id:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('regusername').value = '" & mylogin & "'" in document 1
end tell
```