# Applescript, click checkbox with do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web, applescript

I'm trying to check or uncheck a checkbox using do JavaScript within an AppleScript. The checkbox appears within an iframe named `mainFrame` and within a form named `postForm`... here's the checkbox:

```
<input class="normal" id="apples" name="applesChk" value="<1>" style="visibility: visible" onclick="checkChk(this.checked, 1);" type="checkbox">
```

And here's my AppleScript... this'll be a little embarrassing:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"

        set windowNumber to 1
        repeat the number of windows times
            if "(item)" is in name of window windowNumber then
                set tempWindowName to name of window windowNumber
            else
                set windowNumber to windowNumber + 1
            end if
        end repeat

    end tell
end tell

tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.['apples'].click()" in window tempWindowName
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsById('apples')[0].click()" in window tempWindowName
    do JavaScript "document.forms['postForm']['apples'].checked = true" in window tempWindowName
    do JavaScript "document.frames['mainFrame']['apples'].checked = true" in window tempWindowName
    do JavaScript "document.frames['mainFrame'].forms['postForm']['apples'].checked = true" in window tempWindowName
end tell
```

I get the window by looking for window names containing a certain phrase, then I work with that. Then you can see my five attempts at checking the box. I've really struggled to follow other examples successfully here... any advice appreciated, where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `do JavaScript "document.forms['postForm']['apples'].value = true" in window tempWindowName`? Maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615180/making-applescript-fill-form/22620523#22620523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You must specify a **document**  or a **tab** when you use the `do javascript` command, like this:

```
do JavaScript "some command" in document 1 -- not -->window 1
do JavaScript "some command" in (current tab of window 1)
```

---

2: You can find a document (or the current tab) by name, like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set tDoc to first document whose name contains "(item)"
    do JavaScript "some command" in tDoc
    -- or 
    --set tTab to current tab of (first window whose name contains "(item)"
    --do JavaScript "some command" in tTab
end tell
```

---

3: `frames` is a property of an `window`, so you must use `window.frames` (not `document.frames`)

---

4: `document.getElementsById('apples')[0].click()` is wrong

1. **getElementsById** is not a valid command, use **getElementById**
2. getElementById return one element, not an **array**.
3. `document.getElementById('apples').click()` is correct

---

If your information is correct, this script will work (if the iframe is not within another iframe):

```
tell application "Safari"
    set tDoc to first document whose name contains "(item)"
    do JavaScript "window.frames['mainFrame'].document.getElementById('apples').checked=true" in tDoc
end tell
```

This script has been tested on a HTML document which contains an iframe (`<iframe name="mainFrame" ...`), this iframe contains a form (`<form action="demo_form.asp" name="postForm" ...`), and this form contains the checkbox (`<input class="normal" id="apples" ... type="checkbox">`).

Comment: Thanks @jackjr300 - for such a comprehensive answer, I'm learning well here. Suffice it to say it works perfectly. Thank you!